# Can't suppress GCC -Wextra warning

Tags: c++, gcc, suppress-warnings, gcc-warning, g++4.8

I use Boost.Log v2 in one of my projects and I get the following warning when I build it:

```
C:\boost-1.55\include\boost\log\utility\setup\common_attributes.hpp:22: In file included from C:\boost-1.55\include/boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp:22:0,
PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT_NAME\main.cpp:12: from ..\PROJECT_NAME\main.cpp:12:
C:\boost-1.55\include\boost\log\attributes\counter.hpp:-1: In instantiation of 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::attribute_value boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::attributes::counter<T>::impl_generic::get_value() [with T = unsigned int]':
PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT_NAME\main.cpp:44: required from here
C:\boost-1.55\include\boost\log\attributes\counter.hpp:133: avertissement : address requested for 'next', which is declared 'register' [-Wextra]
     return make_attribute_value(next);
                                     ^
```

I'd like to remove this warning since I can't fix it as it's part of the Boost library. However, I did not find any `-Wno-xxx` option to remove it (`-Wno-extra` doesn't work). I'm using GCC 4.8.2.

How can I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may disable the warning when you include boost library

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wextra" // address requested for 'next', which is declared 'register'

//#include "boost/header_you_want.h"

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```